# система оплаты между пользователями. внутри приложения

Tags: android, ios, swift

Как реализовать систему оплаты в приложении по схеме приложений-такси: одни пользователи отправляют оплату другим с удержанием некоторой комиссии приложением?

Comment: Оплата в приложении через банковскую карту - иначе это противоречит правилам AppStore. Начисление - переводом на электронный кошелёк, банковский счет/карту, счет мобильного телефона. При этом в России по законодательству надо удерживать налог с получателя, если он физ.лицо.